# Service Worker DOMException: Registration failed - storage error

Tags: firebase, browser, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

While implement Fire-base cloud messaging in browser with help of Service Worker getting an error  "DOMException: Registration failed - storage error" please help why i am getting this error

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was caused by `create-react-app`'s own service worker unregistration logic at the very bottom of `index.js`:

```
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

It was conflicting with the fact of using a service worker in the middle of our own application's logic.

Solution was simple – just removing that line from `index.js`

Answer (score 0):

This means that your Service Worker has stored so much data that the storage available to it is full, and upon SW installation it tries to store even more which in turn leads to an error.

You have to either manually remove stuff from your storage or use some library that automatically handles these situations for you in a way or another (eg. removes stuff FIFO style).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But can you please suggest me how to remove data from service worker storage.

Comment: i dont have anything stored by serviceworker, but still I am getting the above error